# using atomicAdd with float parametrs

Tags: cuda, atomic

I need usage atomic function **atomicAdd(float * adress, float value).**
My video card supports compute capability 2.1.
I have read that to use atomicAdd for floating point operations in gpu with compute capability 2.1, we have to specify **sm_20 arch**. I'm using Visual Studio 2010. I have changed "compute_10,sm_10" to "compute_20,sm_20" in Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->CUDA C/C++->Device.
But I have error:"no instance of overloaded function "atomicAdd" matches the argument list".
I can see that during compilation still used  arch sm_11. 
Where should I specify the architecture used. Please help me.

Comment: All these device functions are implemented using templates. Are you 100% sure that *both* arguments are `float`? Could you edit your question to show a simple piece of code which illustrates the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try right clicking on the .cu file, open the preferences and see if the Device setting has been changed there.

Comment: Thank you. This help me. Now it works. (I'm right clicking on solution before that)

Answer (score 0):

In the configuration properties, under CUDA C/C++->Device you have already set the Code Generation to compute_20,sm_20 (although you should probably set sm_21 if your GPU has capability 2.1) but you should also ensure that you untick the "Inherit from parent or project defaults".

Then check that the properties for the file in question have not overriden the project settings (basically repeat the above but this time the "Inherit from parent or project defaults" should be checked and there should be no additional entries).